Error: The superclass, 'TextTheme', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/waveui-0.0.10+9/lib/configs/styles/text_theme.dart:6:9: Error: The superclass, 'TextTheme', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
const WaveTextTheme({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
how to resolve this?
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/waveui-0.0.10+9/lib/configs/styles/text_theme.dart:6:9: Error: The superclass, 'TextTheme', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
const WaveTextTheme({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

pkg seems new, can you try running their example code and make sure to run without any (src)modification

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
